# I upgraded to react 16.0 then I have to install npm install prop-types package separately. But some node modules even not updated

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

What should I do? Because I have to check lot of dependency. When I upgraded after I changed my files but when it’s running I gotta errors from some node modules files. It’s error showing one by one. When one file fixed, then have to run again and then showed it again another node module Proptypes undefined. 
[[this is error , i have got from node modules ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLBln.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLBln.png)

Comment: Please show the error message as of we can't help you like that.

Comment: I have uploaded can you pls and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try updating all the the Packages by `npm update` or give a `npm outdated` and check whether if some of them are not updated yet. Let me know if its fixed

Comment: I used npm update. But it’s updated but some packages still they are not updated . So what should I do? My project large scale app now. App can’t run now because of this reason.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the node modules you are using some may still use the old PropTypes From react package, so you may need to fork it and update it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. You mean Have to do fork?